# Removing Cellspacing under Footer (tfoot)

Tags: html, css, html-table, footer

I have a problem, where I cannot remove white space under my footer, since I created the whole site in a Table (instructions by my professor) and I have used border-collapse:seperate

This is my tfoot code:

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="3" class="footer">
     <section class="levifooter">
        <h2>Sed ut perspiciatis unde</h2>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus 
            error sit voluptatem rem aperiam, ab illo inventore 
            veritatis et quasi architecto beataea vitae dicta suntaa
             explicabo.Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error
              sit voluptatem rem aperiam, ab illo inventore veritatis 
              et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
              </p>
    </section>
    <section class="desnifooter">
       <h2>eaque ipsa quae</h2></a>
       <a href=#><p>accusantium doloremque</p></a><hr>
       <a href=#><p>laudantium, totam</p></a><hr>
       <a href=#><p>quae ab illo</p></a>
    </section>
 </tfoot>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  color:white;
  background-color:#666666;
}

.footer a {
  color:white;
}

.footer hr {
  border-color:white;
}
```

It looks like this:
[image: space under footer]
I have been trying to remove the space under it for a long time, but I just cant seem to get it to work. I have tried using margins, paddings, even tried creating classes for tfoot, td and tr... nothing worked.

It is supposed to look something like this:
[image: correct footer]

Comment: Do you know how to use your dev tools? You should be able to inspect that element and see exactly what's causing it. And I can't believe your professor is making you use a table for standard content! Unless this is a course on making email newsletters...

Comment: please add your css part

Comment: Hey, yes. I know what is causing it, it is the cause of using border-spacing, as I have stated above, but I cannot restart my whole site, ,because of this. There must be a way to fix this.